# Как сделать прозрачный текст с помощью PIL?

Tags: python, изображения, pillow

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

filename = Image.open("1.png").convert("RGBA")

def add_watermark(image, watermark):
    image_width, image_height = image.size
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    font_size = int(image_width / 3)
    font = ImageFont.truetype('1.ttf',font_size)
    x, y = int(image_width / 2), int(image_height / 2)


    fill_color = (255, 255, 0, 128)
    draw.text((x, y), watermark, font=font, fill=fill_color, anchor="ms")

    image.save("1_watermarked.png")
    image.show()

add_watermark(filename, "proof")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Он не прозрачный.
А когда открываю в visual code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь разница между тем, что вы **сделали**, и что вы **хотели сделать**. ;-)

1. Что вы **сделали**:

   ```
    fill_color = (255, 255, 0, 128)
    draw.text((x, y), watermark, font=font, fill=fill_color, anchor="ms")
   ```

   Вы просто **заменили** пиксели картинки  пикселами текста. Да, пиксели текста имеют значение альфа канала менее 255, т.е. они (частично) прозрачные, но через не вы *не видите пиксели оригинальной картинки под ними,* потому что **таких пикселов уже нету** — вы их в оригинальной картинке все уже заменили!

   Да, в вашей новой картинке теперь **будут частично прозрачные пиксели**, но они бы себя проявились только тогда, **когда бы под ними была какая-то другая картинка**.
2. Что вы **хотели сделать**:
   Наложить картинку с текстом на картинку вашей оригинальной картинки, но не так, чтобы пиксели текста *заменили* пиксели картинки,  а только **повлияли** на пиксели картинки под ним.

---

Вы можете

1. сначала создать **новую, совсем прозрачную картинку** (с теми же размерами, как ваша оригинальная картинка):

   ```
   watermark_text = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
   ```
2. затем (после получения контекста) **поставить на ее ваш текст с полупрозрачными пикселями:**

   ```
   dt = ImageDraw.Draw(watermark_text)
   dt.text((x, y), watermark, font=font, fill=fill_color, anchor="ms")
   ```
3. Теперь у вас уже 2 картинки - картинка с текстом и ваша оригинальная картинка.
   Поставите картинку с текстом на вашу оригинальную картинку, **не заменяя одни пиксели на другие**:

   ```
   image = Image.alpha_composite(image, watermark_text)
   ```

---

*Вся ваша, но теперь уже исправленная функция:*

```
def add_watermark(image, watermark):
    image_width, image_height = image.size
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    font_size = int(image_width / 3)
    font = ImageFont.truetype('1.ttf',font_size)
    x, y = int(image_width / 2), int(image_height / 2)
        
    fill_color = (255, 255, 0, 128)
    
    watermark_text = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
    dt = ImageDraw.Draw(watermark_text)
    dt.text((x, y), watermark, font=font, fill=fill_color, anchor="ms")
    
    image = Image.alpha_composite(image, watermark_text)

    image.save("1_watermarked.png")
    image.show()
```

---

Тест:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]